# Excel blank row inserter

Tags: python, beginner, excel, file

I wrote a program as an excercise, to check the `openpyxl` module, which inserts blank rows into an excel file. See the docstring in the code for more description.

I would like to know what you think about the code.
Is it easy / difficult to follow?
Is it structured good / bad? 
What can be improved?

**blank_row_inserter.py**

```
"""
Reads in an Excel document to add blank lines.
The user can run the program in command line with arguments or input
the information at runtime.
Things to input:
-Filename of excel file to manipulate
-Start row for blank lines
-Count of blank rows to insert

The changes made by the program get saved in a new excel file.
It is saved as updated_{filename}.xlsx
"""

import sys
from typing import Tuple
from copy import copy
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.utils import column_index_from_string

def is_positive_number(input_string: str) -> bool:
    """Checks if input is valid to use for the excel file"""
    return input_string.isdigit() and int(input_string) >= 1


def enter_positive_number(user_message) -> int:
    """
    Prompts the user until positive number was entered and returns then
    the number
    """
    while True:
        input_string = input(user_message)
        if is_positive_number(input_string):
            return int(input_string)


def user_input() -> Tuple[int, int, str]:
    """
    First looks for data on the command line. If command line input is
    not valid the user is prompted to put in the values manually.
    Returns start_row, count_of_blank_rows and filename
    """
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        start_blank_row_input: str = sys.argv[1]
        blank_rows_input: str = sys.argv[2]

        if (is_positive_number(start_blank_row_input) and
                is_positive_number(blank_rows_input)):
            return (int(start_blank_row_input),
                    int(blank_rows_input), sys.argv[3])

    start_blank_row = enter_positive_number(
        "Enter start of blank rows:\n")
    blank_rows = enter_positive_number(
        "Enter how many blank rows to insert:\n")
    filename: str = input("Enter filename:\n")
    return start_blank_row, blank_rows, filename


def save_workbook_excel_file(workbook, filename):
    """Tris to save created data to excel file"""
    try:
        workbook.save(filename)
    except PermissionError:
        print("Error: No permission to save file.")


def copy_cells(
        source_sheet, target_sheet,
        row_start: int, row_end: int, row_offset: int,
        column_start: int, column_end: int, column_offset: int):
    """
    Copies cells from one sheet to the other including its style.
    It is possible to enter blank rows or columns into the new sheet.
    """
    for row in range(row_start, row_end):
        for column in range(column_start, column_end):
            source = source_sheet.cell(row=row, column=column)
            target = target_sheet.cell(
                row=row + row_offset, column=column + column_offset)
            target.value = copy(source.value)
            if source.has_style:
                target.font = copy(source.font)
                target.border = copy(source.border)
                target.fill = copy(source.fill)
                target.number_format = copy(source.number_format)
                target.protection = copy(source.protection)
                target.alignment = copy(source.alignment)


def copy_row_dimensions(
        source_sheet, target_sheet,
        start_blank_row: int, blank_rows: int):
    """
    Copies the dimension of rows from one sheet to the other.
    It is possible to copy with an offset to "insert" new rows
    into the new sheet
    """
    for row_number, row_dim in source_sheet.row_dimensions.items():
        if row_number >= start_blank_row:
            row_number = row_number + blank_rows
        target_sheet.row_dimensions[row_number] = copy(row_dim)


def copy_column_dimensions(
        source_sheet, target_sheet,
        start_blank_column: int, blank_columns: int):
    """
    Copies the dimension of columns from one sheet to the other.
    It is possible to copy with an offset to "insert" new columns
    into the new sheet
    """
    for column_letter, column_dim in source_sheet.column_dimensions.items():
        column_index = column_index_from_string(column_letter)
        if column_index >= start_blank_column:
            column_index = column_index + blank_columns
        column_letter = get_column_letter(column_index)
        target_sheet.column_dimensions[column_letter] = copy(column_dim)


def blank_row_inserter():
    """Main logic to insert blank rows"""
    start_blank_row: int
    blank_rows: int
    filename: str
    start_blank_row, blank_rows, filename = user_input()

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheet_names = workbook.sheetnames
    sheet = workbook[sheet_names[0]]
    max_row = sheet.max_row
    max_column = sheet.max_column
    workbook.create_sheet(index=0, title='tmp_sheet')
    new_sheet = workbook['tmp_sheet']

    # Copy everything before blank area
    copy_cells(
        source_sheet=sheet, target_sheet=new_sheet,
        row_start=1, row_end=start_blank_row, row_offset=0,
        column_start=1, column_end=max_column, column_offset=0)

    # Copy with row offset
    copy_cells(
        source_sheet=sheet, target_sheet=new_sheet,
        row_start=start_blank_row, row_end=max_row, row_offset=blank_rows,
        column_start=1, column_end=max_column, column_offset=0)

    copy_row_dimensions(
        source_sheet=sheet, target_sheet=new_sheet,
        start_blank_row=start_blank_row, blank_rows=blank_rows)

    copy_column_dimensions(
        source_sheet=sheet, target_sheet=new_sheet,
        start_blank_column=0, blank_columns=0)

    sheet_name = sheet.title
    del workbook[sheet_name]
    new_sheet.title = sheet_name
    save_workbook_excel_file(workbook, 'updated_' + filename)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    blank_row_inserter()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while True:
    input_string = input(user_message)
    if is_positive_number(input_string):
        return int(input_string)
```

Fine, but the user should be told if they have invalid input; so add an error message to the end of that loop.

```
if len(sys.argv) == 4:
    start_blank_row_input: str = sys.argv[1]
    blank_rows_input: str = sys.argv[2]

    if (is_positive_number(start_blank_row_input) and
            is_positive_number(blank_rows_input)):
        return (int(start_blank_row_input),
                int(blank_rows_input), sys.argv[3])
```

The problem with this approach is that if the user *tries* to enter command-line input but it's invalid (has the wrong number of args, for instance), their input is silently discarded. You should differentiate between "no input" and "invalid input", the latter showing an error message and the former continuing to your input prompts.

```
"""Tris to save created data to excel file"""
```

You probably meant "tries".

For these two lines:

```
row_number = row_number + blank_rows

column_index = column_index + blank_columns
```

Use the `+=` operator.

Comment: Im a bit surprised i was on the train that `+=` does not exist unlike for example `c++`. Was it added lately?

Comment: It's been around for a very, very long time: https://docs.python.org/release/2.0/ref/delimiters.html